# Safari and Bootstrap 4 - automatic grid breaks

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, grid-layout, bootstrap-4

This bootstrap 4 code

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col"><small>Some text here</small></div>
        <div class="col"><small>Some text here</small></div>
        <div class="col"><small>Some text here</small></div>
        .... add more columns until they should wrap
        <div class="col"><small>Some text here</small></div>
        <div class="col"><small>Some text here</small></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

will automatically wrap in Chrome and firefox just as expected. In safari, though, it will not wrap into the next line but go beyond the page margins.

Is there a work around?

Please note that - depending on your viewport width - you have to add a bunch of `<div class="col"><small>Some text here</small></div>`to make the effect visible.

Comment: It might be helpful to add this as an issue to https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues

Comment: @Armin added the issue: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/21967

Answer (score 1):

You could try using flexbox instead, e.g.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="d-flex p-2"><small>Some text here</small></div>
        <div class="d-flex p-2"><small>Some text here</small></div>
        <div class="d-flex p-2"><small>Some text here</small></div>
        <div class="d-flex p-2"><small>Some text here</small></div>
        <div class="d-flex p-2"><small>Some text here</small></div>
        <div class="d-flex p-2"><small>Some text here</small></div>
        <div class="d-flex p-2"><small>Some text here</small></div>
        <div class="d-flex p-2"><small>Some text here</small></div>
        <div class="d-flex p-2"><small>Some text here</small></div>
        <div class="d-flex p-2"><small>Some text here</small></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yu7atpzf/1/). This may or may not achieve what you're after - you can probably tweak it, Bootstrap 4 flex support is pretty powerful since alpha6.

http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/flexbox/

Comment: But I thought that flex is always active in B4?

Comment: Well you asked for a workaround, and this one might work :) I think you essentially just discovered a Safari-related bug, since you're correct that your version *should* work.

Comment: I will def try it. I also found out that there are special wrapping classes I could try. Still, I think it is a tiny flaw (in Safari or BT)

Answer (score 0):

I edited your JSFiddle by adding:

```
 .row { width: 100%; }                                                 
 .col { display:inline-block !important; }
```

It seems like its doing the trick. I used Safari 5.1.9 if that helps you out.

Cheers!

Comment: You will have to go a bit deeper within your CSS coding to appy it to multiple styles if you are intending on adding this to columns with `col-lg-#'/col-md-#/etc`.